# Opera Dragonfly vs. Firebug

Tags: firefox, firebug, opera, opera-dragonfly

I'm Opera user for browsing and Firefox user for developing. Simply I can't work without Firebug and any other tools doesn't fit for me. Geeks from Opera often offers to use  [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) which purpose is almost the same like Firebug (JS debugger, DOM/CSS inspector, JS console, page load analysis, etc.). I've tried Dragonfly but returned to Firebug because of these reasons:

- Firebug loads faster than Dragonfly (ex. when inspecting element);
- <strike>Dragonfly doesn't have (or I have not found) how quickly disable some property of css. On FB you simply need click an icon next to prop.</strike> It already has.

I'm interested does anyone uses Dragonfly instead ob FB or any other tool? Why (not)? What main differences you see between these both tools?

Comment: Firebug user here. I have looked at Dragonfly once or twice, but cannot give an educated answer.

Comment: "Firebug loads faster than Dragonfly (ex. when inspecting element);" not true for almost a year(since first versions of dragonfly with offline cache).

Answer (score 11):

you may or may not be aware that Opera Dragonfly is a sort of web application, loading from Opera's server on first usage and whenever it's upgraded. If you re-open it and the server version is not updated, it should load quickly from cache. I'm not sure that's *always* the case, YMMV, and I can completely understand that its unpredictable load time can be annoying. However, this way your are always using the latest version of Dragonfly without having to update any extension.

Which brings me to the second point: disabling CSS properties. This is now supported in a pretty obvious way in the latest version. I suggest you just try opening Dragonfly again :-D

Regarding comparisons, I'm inherently too biased to comment on this question... But anyway: My general feeling is that Firebug was a giant leap in web debugger UI design (if you're old enough to have used Venkman you know what I mean), however under the hood it doesn't feel stable to use. My use case is mostly the JS debugger (DOM inspector has always been more reliable) and I've seen the debugger misbehave in many weird little ways over the years. I'll quickly add that Dragonfly is not *much* better yet, it has known problems that can throw you completely off the track when stepping. The current version of Firebug may well be more stable than all past versions, but I'm still a bit reluctant to use it for complex JS debugging tasks, and prefer Dragonfly or Chrome's inspector. YMMV  again.

..the main reason I prefer Dragonfly probably is that this user JS lets me use Dragonfly to step through ANY random script, no matter if it's sent over the wire as a whitespace-free text blob:
http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/2008/05/13/script-formatter-user-js

But then, my use case is debugging ANY random page while most people's use case is to debug their own nicely formatted scripts :)

Comment: (BTW I don't have an overview of what Dragonfly versions go with what Opera versions - make sure you use the latest Opera version to get the latest Dragonfly..)

Comment: Finally disabling CSS properties is here! It should be fresh update, because I have not seen this before few weeks ago.

Comment: Disabling and modifying existing CSS works, but adding CSS rules is not possible, is it?

Comment: Sure it is, just double-click an existing entry to go to editing mode, put the cursor behind the semicolon at the end and press enter. (It could certainly be more easy to find this feature..)

Answer (score 2):

I use the developper tools of all the browsers! Even for Internet Explorer there are extra downloads for developers!

The problem is: it's not beacause one thing works in firefox, it works in IE6,7,8, Opera And Chrome.

What I like about internet exlporer tool is that you can choose which version you are debugging. So you do not need to download the collection pack (because 6 and 7 are almost the same)

All the tools have almost the same features.

Comment: btw, an overview:
http://www.favbrowser.com/internet-explorer-developer-tools-vs-firefox-firebug-vs-safari-web-inspector-vs-opera-dragonfly/

Answer (score 2):

Well I would say dragonfly is much better than firebug. It provides all the tools that are present in firebug but you just have to figure it out. There is CSS autocomplete. But for that you have to press `down key` for and adding css is very easy. Just scroll down to the bottom of the css bar and there will be written `new style`. And dragonfly also provides the Line no of styles. On the right top corner of the style declaration.

Comment: The only thing I can't find in Dragonfly is an equivalent of Firebug's `DOM` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Have to agree there, I spend 90% of my time making things work in ie and having the ability to render in ie7 or 8 with the ie developer tools is a big bonus.

When it comes to ie6 i tend to fire it up through spoon.net and then use the firebug lite bookmarklet to hack away, however these days you'll already have a rough idea of what will and won't work before you start.

...unfortunately working in finance a lot of your users will be stuck on ie6 for a considerable time so you just have to go with it.

personally i'm trying the other debuggers out to see if they're better than firebug but so far they're ok at best, however with the shift to webkit browsers Google Chrome's already got my vote.

Answer (score -3):

```
CSS editing capabilities      Firebug   |   Dragonfly
                              _______________________
CSS autocomplete              Yes       |   No
Ease in adding new css        Very easy |   Very difficult
Line no of styles             Yes       |   No
Page rendering while inspect  Normal    |   Inspected element get locked
Ruler                         Useless   |   Very handy (on the screenshot)
Color pallete                 No        |   Yes
Tabbed resource browsing      No        |   Yes
Extendability via plugins     Yes       |   No
```

Comment: In DRAGONFLY: For adding new css, you just have to type return on one of the CSS properties. Line numbering: There are direct anchors to the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Dragonfly looks promising. 1] 'New Style' is a way to add a new CSS declaration to an un-styled element (ie. an element not already have a declaration in the CSS file.), still the Firebug's 'Edit element style' is far more intuitive. 2] Regarding line number, direct anchors take you to the top of the CSS file, not to the style in question. Also to port the changes to the local CSS file you are in need of the line numbers.

Comment: which version of dragonfly you are using. because I have access to direct line number. right now in Opera 11.60 and Opera Dragonfly: 1.2011.10.31.2 Release task 2 DFL-2559
Révision numéro: 5171:51e826f9ce9e, default, Opera Dragonfly 1.2011.10.31.2 Release task 2